# System Callout Exception Error

Tags: apex, rest, trailhead

This is my class where I do the callout

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/Project/*')
global class ProjectCalloutService {
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void postOpportunityToPMS(List<Id> oids){

        Opportunity o = [SELECT ID,Name,Account.Name,CloseDate,Amount FROM Opportunity WHERE Id = :oids[0]];

        ServiceTokens__c s = ServiceTokens__c.getValues('ProjectServiceToken');

        String jsonInput = '{\n' +
        ' "opportunityId" : "'+o.Id+'",\n'+
        ' "opportunityName" : "'+o.Name+'",\n'+
        ' "accountName" : "'+o.Account.Name+'",\n'+
        ' "closeDate" : "'+String.ValueOf(o.CloseDate).mid(0,10)+'",\n'+   
        ' "amount" : '+o.Amount+'\n'+
        '}';

        HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
        req.setEndPoint('callout:ProjectService');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization',s.Token__c);
        req.setBody(jsonInput);

        HTTP h = new HTTP();
        HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);
        System.debug(res);
    }
}
```

As can be seen there is no DML in the above method (only i do System.debug)
This method is being invoked from the process builder which spits out an error as shown below

> An error occurred at element myRule_1_A1 (FlowActionCall).
>       An Apex error occurred: System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out
>       This report lists the elements that the flow interview executed. The report is a beta feature.
>       We welcome your feedback on IdeaExchange.
>       Flow Details
>       Flow Name: Update_Opportunity
>       Type: Workflow
>       Version: 3
>       Status: Active
>       Flow Interview Details
>       Interview Label: Update_Opportunity-3_Opportunity
>       Current User: Aran (0056F000006TVhe)
>       Start time: 30/01/2017 2:16 PM
>       Duration: 0 seconds
>       How the Interview Started
>       Varun Prasad Gunasekaran (0056F000006TVhe) started the flow interview.
>       Some of this flow's variables were set when the interview started.
>       myVariable_old = null
>       myVariable_current = 0066F00000kKoLfQAK
>       ASSIGNMENT: myVariable_waitStartTimeAssignment
>       {!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} Equals {!Flow.CurrentDateTime}
>       Result
>       {!myVariable_waitStartTimeVariable} = "30/01/2017 2:16 PM"
>       DECISION: myDecision
>       Executed this outcome: myRule_1
>       Outcome conditions: and
>       1. {!myVariable_current.StageName} (Closed Won) Equals Closed Won
>       2. {!myVariable_current.Type} (New Project) Equals New Project
>       Logic: All conditions must be true (AND)
>       PROJECTCALLOUTSERVICE (APEX): myRule_1_A1
>       Inputs:
>       oids = {!myVariable_current.Id} (0066F00000kKoLfQAK)

I am not able to understand as to why I am shown this error when I am not doing any DML at all.

Comment: if a PB is invoking it then it seems pretty clear it is being invoked during a DML right?

Comment: Move the logic to a `@future` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make callout in future method.

```
@future
public static void calloutMethod(String jsonInput){
 HTTPRequest req = new HTTPRequest();
        req.setEndPoint('callout:ProjectService');
        req.setMethod('POST');
        req.setHeader('Authorization',s.Token__c);
        req.setBody(jsonInput);

        HTTP h = new HTTP();
        HTTPResponse res = h.send(req);
        System.debug(res);
}
```